# Retrieving URL from saved plist file

Tags: objective-c, xcode, macos, cocoa

Hi i am new with objective c.

I am saving my URL data in plist file under resource. here is my code.

```
NSString *plistPath =[[[NSBundle mainBundle] resourcePath] 
           stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"myfile.plist"];

NSDictionary *plistDict = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]
                                       dictionaryRepresentation];

if([plistDict writeToFile:plistPath atomically:YES]) {
    NSLog(@"success");
} else {
    NSLog(@"error");
}
```

Now i want to retrieve URL from that saved plist (my file.plist), How i can retrieve this that i can use that url for web view.

e.g:

```
urlString.stringValue = ????
```

Here i am using `urlString.stringValue` for webview.

```
[[webview mainFrame] loadRequest:[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:
                [NSURL URLWithString:urlString.stringValue]]];
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, you don't need to save NSUserDefaults to a file yourself.  Its contents are saved automatically at periodic intervals, or you can call `synchronize` to save immediately.

But if you want to save a dictionary to a plist, use the `writeToFile:atomically:` method as you already have.  Then you can load it again by creating a new dictionary with the contents of the plist:

```
[NSDictionary dictionaryWithContentsOfFile:plistPath];
```